# Can't create new Kotlin project after updating to Android Studio 4.2

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-4.2

I updated Android studio 4.2 but I wasn't able to create new project kotlin

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0-release-764.
 Searched in the following locations:
   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0-release- 
764/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0-release-764.pom
   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0-release-764/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0-release-764.pom
 Required by:
     project :

Possible solution:
- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at 
 https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Comment: remove "-release-764"  e.g.  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0"

Comment: But then there is a warning from lint "Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.5.0) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.5.0-release-764)" If the version is bundled with the IDE, how come gradle can't find it?

Comment: It's fixed in Android Studio 4.2.1: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/05/android-studio-421-available.html

Comment: Generic solution to`Could not resolve all artifacts` which will help in future as well too, faced either because of some bug in IDE or mistakenly used wrong artifact version. Do let me know if that helps. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67760444/4828650

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The error is clear Gradle was unable to find the library that you declared

Possible fixes

**Location**

> Project -> build.gradle

```
//update it
dependencies {
  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30"
}
```

**Edited** kotlin has released stable version of version 1.5.0 last night you can use this version to stay up-to-date

```
dependencies {
  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0"
}
```

Comment: Essentially reduce the kotlin-gradle-plugin version from "1.5.0-release-764" to "1.4.30"

Comment: You can also use "1.5.0" (if you want to use the latest Kotlin version)

Comment: Can I config version by default? Start new project with this version

Comment: I know we can just use 1.5.0, but Android Studio warns us that we have to use 1.5.0-release-764 while this versions seems not deployed, or not able to be gotten from maven.

`Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.5.0) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.5.0-release-764) `. I remember I had same warning before as well too, and I could *avoid* warning with same solution like this time

Comment: and don't forget to add `mavenCentral()` if missing

Comment: I first tried 1.5.0 and the build succeded. But afterward, when running the emulator, I received other errors. Now I use 1.4.30 and that has finally worked.

Comment: Catastrophe. Without StackOverflow one would be lost in such a situation. How is an error like that possible?

Comment: It was a bug in Android Studio. It's fixed in Android Studio 4.2.1: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/05/android-studio-421-available.html

Comment: @michael.zech I have written an answer to give a solution to generic to`Could not resolve all artifacts` which will help in future as well to face either because of some bug in IDE or mistakenly used wrong artifact version. Do let me know if that helps.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67760444/4828650

Answer (score 64):

Worked for me:

**Location: build.gradle**

change

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0-release-764"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

to

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

Comment: Just to add more explicit detail, be sure to make the changes `build.grade (Project: <app_name>)` file

Answer (score 24):

You should know that there are "two" build.gradle files in the Gradle Scripts on Android Studio, the build.gradle(Project) and build.gradle(Module). It took me hours to realize that I've been looking at the Module version of build.gradle while attempting to fix this and wasn't able to find the proper kotlin version variables to change.

build.gradle(Project) is [the proper build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WpPr.png) you want to make changes to.

From there change

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0-release-764"
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

to

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

and try to rebuild your project again. This should work.

Answer (score 7):

New Android Studio 4.2.1 has been released with Patches.

If upgrading does not fix your issues, Try Restart and reset caches.

Otherwise use the solution provided above which is to replace in build.gradle

from

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0-release-764"
```

to

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
```

Answer (score 7):

As everybody now knows the solution, we have to get rid of `-release-764` as there is no such artifact with this version.

The same can be validated below

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin

I just wanted to add a few pointers, whenever you get any such error(`Could not resolve all artifacts` for any library `Could not find xyz`) in future for any of the android's library.

Most of the library we use are resolved by

- `google()`
- `mavenCentral()`

If its a Google's Android library

- Search google's maven repo https://maven.google.com/ to see if the version you are looking for is even the correct one or what is the latest version of the library exists.
- Few of the google's android library is still available at mavenCentral, you can use https://mvnrepository.com/ or https://search.maven.org/ to search or validate the version of your library

If it's another android library and you haven't specified any specific repositories for them apart from `mavenCentral()` then you can use https://mvnrepository.com/ or https://search.maven.org/ to search or validate the version of your library

If in case you are using `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` as a repository for your library then you can search here https://jitpack.io/.

Hopefully, these pointers will be of any use to someone, this always helps me in case I am getting any such error.

Comment: That are definitely useful insights. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @michael.zech glad that you find it useful, if you feel this will help others as well please upvote and show your support. Thanks

Comment: Well all I had to do was add mavenCentral() in buildscript -> repositories in top level gradle. It couldn't find the appropriate version before. I added mavencentral in allprojects->repositories, but forgot to add it up top.

Answer (score 7):

> Change the dependency

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0-release-764"
   dependencies {
       classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"
       classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
   }
```

> To this

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.10"
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"     
    }
```

Comment: Managed to do this once Android Studio was updated from version 4.2 to 4.2.1, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

On new project create

```
buildscript {        ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0-release-764"
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
```

this is work for me

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.30"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

> When ever I started creating a new project this error occurs with the
> gradle plugin.

UPDATE  **14th May 2021** ->

***GOTO -> gradle -> build.gradle -> in the code -> dependencies -> Change Classpath ->*** *classpath* **"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0"**

*and you're good to go.*

Answer (score 4):

**Change From**

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0-release-764" //Remove release-764
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}
```

**Change To**

```
 buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0" //Here is the change have to add this Version 
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please update your **Android Studio** to **4.2.1(Released on May 13, 2021)**, the new **Stable Version**.
This issue has been resolved in that:-

> **Kotlin Issue #187403740:** Android Studio 4.2.0 generates projects with the wrong Kotlin version: "1.5.0-release-764"

**Change Log**

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/05/android-studio-421-available.html

Answer (score 2):

SIMPLEST SOLUTION FOR YOUR PROBLEM:

change :

ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0-release-764"

to :

ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"

in your build.gradle project level

Answer (score 2):

If anyone was facing a similar issues for a Java project then
Here is a sample `build.gradle` file (Project Level)

*Caution:* Notice the `mavenCentral()` method added there, this is a **must** to be added for gradle `4.2.1+`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {


        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com/"
        }

        google()

        maven() {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }

        jcenter()

        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was easily resolved by replacing jcenter() with mavenCentral() in the buildscript and allprojects repositories for build.grade.

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency into your build.gradle

```
 classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fast solution, just select 1.4.32 Kotlin version when Android Studio prompt configure Kotlin window.

At this time - ***May 13, 2021***  - selecting 1.5.0 its giving me gradle issues