# Android Studio 4.2 Kotlin Plugin Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Cannot build a new project using Android Studio 4.2 because of the following error:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0-release-764.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0-release-764/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0-release-764.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0-release-764/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0-release-764.pom
     Required by:
         project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

When I changed the Kotlin plugin version from `ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0-release-764"` to `ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"` app builds successfully but the following warning appears:

```
Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.5.0) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.5.0-release-764)
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67400029/cant-new-project-kotlin-after-update-android-studio-4-2/67400706#67400706

Comment: But I want to use the latest `Kotlin` version

Comment: As it is not released as a stable version yet, Kotlin 1.5 should be used in Android Studio Canary instead of the latest stable version

Comment: @Wang who said it's not stable? Where did you get this info?

Comment: I'm thinking this is a bug with the new release. Any time I got this warning, updating the version made the warning go away and I was at the latest stable version. This appears to be impossible with the new version, unless there is some missing gradle setting that is preventing it from finding the bundled version.

Comment: @Wang it is already stable as it moves away from RC to release.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-11590

"the problem will be fixed in 1.5.10 update"

Answer (score 12):

**Change From**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0-release-764"
......}
```

**Change To**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
....}
```

Change the Kotlin Version Issue will be cleared.

Comment: I'm already mentioned that in the question but what about the warning!?

Answer (score 3):

I went to the build.gradle file and changed the `ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"` to `ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.32"`, as that was the version of an older project which successfully built.

Comment: Again I want to use the latest stable version of Kotlin which is `1.5.0`
Also, If I used this `1.4.32` warning still exists.

Comment: Well apparently 1.4.32 is the latest stable version lol 1.5.0 doesn't seem to be working right

Answer (score 2):

I was using the same version of `kotlin-gradle-plugin` bundled with the IDE, which is 1.5.10, in Android studio 4.2.1, and for me disabling the 'Block connections to untrusted servers' in my anti-virus fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

According to Android Studio's message, Kotlin's latest stable version is `1.5.0-release-764`. If you want to (or in this case I guess everyone needs to) use version `1.5.0`:

1. Go to `Tools` in the menu
2. Go to `Kotlin`
3. Choose `Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates`
4. In the drop-down, choose the early access preview version of 1.5.x and then click OK.

Gradle sync will now configure the Studio with `Kotlin 1.5.0`.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't fix the warning

Answer (score 0):

if you work on flutter project ,you just need to update flutter sdk run that command in terminal:

```
flutter upgrade
```

After updating , new flutter version  will fix that errors automatically.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31052936)