# Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.5.0) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.5.0-release-764)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

how fix warning? `Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.5.0) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.5.0-release-764)`

after create new project and after fix error (change 1.5.0-release-764 to 1.5.0)

**Simple Solve: Just Update Kotlin plugin!**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't create new Kotlin project after updating to Android Studio 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67400029/cant-create-new-kotlin-project-after-updating-to-android-studio-4-2)

Comment: @AnaniyaJemberu no

Comment: ok well you can ignore it it wont affect your project

Comment: It's fixed in Android Studio 4.2.1: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/05/android-studio-421-available.html

Comment: @MartinMarconcini, how do you mean it is fixed? Android Studio still generates the same warning the OP is asking about.

Comment: Creating a new project in Android Studio 4.2.1 does not put the _incorrect_ kotlin version. The warning will/should not go away, what is fixed is Android Studio making the mistake when creating a new project, instead of the you, the user, having to fix it.

Comment: I've started a new project with 4.2.1 and it still gives this warning. Still it is a warning that can be ignored I guess.

Comment: The warning is fixed in the upcoming Kotlin plugin 1.5.10, which is not released yet I believe. So for the moment it looks like we have to live with this warning.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can ignore this one. I believe this bug will be fixed soon anyway, which should fix this warning too.

Answer (score 5):

According to the comments here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187403740 the issue will be fixed with Kotlin 1.5.10: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-7657

Comment: 1.5.10 is released and has indeed fixed the issue.

Comment: Confirmed! I tried it out today in the morning as well and the warning disappears.

Answer (score -2):

change to

```
dependencies {
  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0"
}
```

Comment: now I have 1.5.0