# Error "> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'." on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

when i create a new project in Android Studio appears this error :

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Hello World Android Studio'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0-release-764.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0-release-764/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0-release-764.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0-release-764/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0-release-764.pom
     Required by:
         project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't create new Kotlin project after updating to Android Studio 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67400029/cant-create-new-kotlin-project-after-updating-to-android-studio-4-2)

Answer (score 1):

In ***build.gradle*** replace
`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"`

with

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0`

and click ***try again***